# (WinError 32) The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'data.csv' -> 'data.csv.bak'

Tags: python, csv

I know there are several questions that are the same as mine but even by referring to them, I can't seem to solve the error. Whenever I "open" the csv file, I always use `with xxx as xx:` which is supposed to prevent this error but I am unsure why I still face this error.

The goal of this code is to update a single value in the "EP" column of the csv file given the specific "uname".

According to the debugger, this is the problematic code `print(",".join(re.fieldnames))` and this is the context of the code:

```
  np = input("Input new electricity unit price") 
  with fileinput.input(files=('data.csv'), inplace=True, mode='r') as g:
        re = csv.DictReader(g)
        print(",".join(re.fieldnames))  # ERROR CAUSED BY THIS LINE
        for x in re:
            if row["Uname"] == uname:
                row["Ep"] = np
            print(",".join([row["Uname"],row["Pw"], row["Ep"]]))
```

I am only showing an extraction of the entire function because I am afraid of being striked for plagiarism. Please let me know if more codes are necessary. Thank you.

Comment: just to make sure, do you also have this csv open in another program? like Excel for example?

Comment: Nope. Made sure to close it.

Comment: Facing same issue on Windows with Python 3.7, what is your setup?